# Как создать возможность добавлять статьи

Tags: html, python, django

Мне нужно добавлять статьи через админ панель, только я не знаю как это сделать, я сделал Models.py. И должен быть листинг всех статей то есть 2 шаблона.

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, а кроме модели, ты еще хоть что-то сделал? Так-то концепция, заложенная в основу Django, называется model-view-controler. Для того, что бы понять, что у тебя не работает, нужны все три компонента, а не только model.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы увидеть модель в панеле администратора Django (`/admin`) и соответственно создавать её экземпляры, Вы должны её зарегестрировать.

Для этого в папке каждого Django-приложения есть файл `admin.py`

***Пример:***

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Articles

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Articles)
```

***P. S.:*** Желательно называть модели в ед.ч (`Article`)